# Factoring Monic Polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible. Then $f$ factors as $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n {f_i}^{e_i}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ and by Hensel's Lemma, each term ${f_i}^{e_i}$ lifts to some factor $F_i$ of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Must $F_i$ be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: You're neglecting some minor details, I think, which are important to your question. e.g. (this one is not directly relevant to your question) do you realize that for $f = x^2 + 2$ and $p=2$, $f$ factors as $x \cdot x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, but $x^2+2$ is the only (monic) factor of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I am aware of the fact you state but that doesn't affect my question. What sort of details do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example consider the case $f(x)=x^2+7$, $p=2$. Modulo $p$ we have
$$
f(x)\equiv x^2+1\equiv(x+1)^2.
$$
The lifted factor in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ has to be $f(x)$ itself. But there is a $w=\sqrt{-7}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so the lifted polynomial factors as $(x-w)(x+w)$ over the 2-adics.

Comment: Here the only modulo $2$ factor $x+1$ has two distinct lifts $x\pm w$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ that are both factors of $f(x)$.

Comment: If an $f_i$ has a lifting, can this lifting be also reducible?

Comment: No. If $f_i$ has a lifting $\tilde f_i\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, and $\tilde f_i$ factors, then you can reduce that factorization modulo $p$ to show that $f_i$ will factor further.

Comment: But all the eventual factors of $F_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ must become $f_i^d$ for some $d\le e_i$, when they are reduced modulo $p$

Comment: Also, is there an easy way to know that $\sqrt{-7}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: A generalization of Hensel lifting works. $1$ is a "good enough" approximation to $\sqrt{-7}$, because $1^2-(-7)$ is divisible by eight. If an approximation is good enough the recursive process of Hensel lifting works out fine. With $f(x)=x^2+7$ we have here $f'(1)=2$ that is not a unit. This prohibits the usual Hensel's lemma from working, but there is a generalization that does work! If the approximation of a root is " much better than just mod $p$", then this allows us to overcome the fact that $f'$ is not a unit at that point. I don't remember the exact statement of the general version.

Comment: @Alexander: See [this excellent answer by Cantlog](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/475845/11619) for an argument proving the existence of $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb{Q}_2$.