# Roots of $X^2-z$ in $2$-adics

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

> Using Hensel's lemma is it true that $X^2-z$, for $z\in \mathbf Z$ any integer have no roots in 2-adics ?

Hensel's lemma only shows, if a root of a polynomial can be lifted to a root in $\mathbf Z_p$, so it doesn't say anything about the nonsolvability but if I look at the conditions:

If there is an $a$ s.t. $f(a)\equiv 0\mod p,\quad f'(a)\not\equiv 0\mod p$

If $p=2$, then the derivative is always zero for a polynomial of the form $X^2-z$, Is there still a root ?

Comment: $X^2-1$ has a root, hasn't it?

Comment: The list of "Related"  questions in the right margin has a lot of helpful material. [This question in particular](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/473595/11619) is useful to you.