# How to determine if an element x is a square in ℤ₂?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I need a criteria how to determine if an element x is a square in ℤ₂ (2-adic numbers).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2$ is misleading. Usually, this means the group with $2$ elements. Additionally, is $x$ an integer or only rational ?

Comment: @Peter *Usually* $\Bbb Z_2$ denotes the 2-adic integers. The cyclic group with 2 elements should possibly be written $Z_2$, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, or $\Bbb Z/(2)$. The fact that it is *often* also written $\Bbb Z_2$ is rather confusing (at least to me) cause there is no common alternative to using $\Bbb Z_2$ for 2-adics ...

Comment: Do you know Hensel's lemma?

Comment: @Peter $2$-adic numbers are not real numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Characterization of integers which has a $2$-adic square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473595/characterization-of-integers-which-has-a-2-adic-square-root)

Comment: @Crostul Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Joanna, welcome to Math.SE. Unfortunately your question was put on hold by popular vote. By studying [this page from the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you can figure out what is bothering the users who voted that way, and what steps you can take to make them change their mind. I have two suggestions. A) This may have been handled already on our site, did you search? B) Dealing with power of two factors is easy here, but for 2-adic units you need a modulo eight argument.

Comment: Re my suggestion A: The question Crostul linked to is very useful to you. Nominally it is about rational integers only, but....

Comment: thank you all very much. I have a lot to learn here